# Ext.NET: How to render a partial view in a loader

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, extjs, partial-views, ext.net

I'm trying to load a partial view when a row is expanded in my grid. My listener looks like this:

```
x.RowExpander()
    .Listeners(ls =>
    {
        ls.Expand.Handler = string.Format("Item.onListRowExpand('{0}', {1}, this);",
            Url.Action("ItemDetail", "My"), Model);
    })
```

This calls into a JavaScript function:

```
onListRowExpand: function(url, listId, expander) {
    var container = App.DashboardPanel;
    var itemId = expander.componentsCache[0].cmp.record.data.Id;
    var panelId = "Details_" + listId + "_" + itemId;

    // Check if the selected panel was selected again. If it was do nothing
    var panel = container.getComponent(panelId);
    if (!panel) {

        // Remove the opened panel so we can add a new one
        if (container.items.getCount() > 1) {
            container.remove(container.items.getAt(1).id);
        }

        // Add the new panel...
        container.add({
            id: panelId,
            closeable: true,
            loader: {
                xtype: "panel",
                url: url,
                renderer: "frame",
                params: {
                    "listId": listId,
                    "itemId": itemId                   }
            }
        });

        container.update();
    }
}
```

This method then calls into a controller:

```
public Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult ItemDetail(int listId, int itemId)
{
    var result = new Ext.Net.MVC.PartialViewResult
    {
        RenderMode = RenderMode.AddTo,
        ContainerId = "MyPanel",
        WrapByScriptTag = false,
        Model = new ItemViewModel
        {
            ListId = listId,
            ItemId = itemId
        }
    };

    return result;
}
```

which is supposed to return a partial view to be added onto the container's `Items`:

```
@(x.Container()
    .ID("MyPanel")
    .Layout(LayoutType.HBox)
    .Loader(x.ComponentLoader()
        .Url(Url.Action("ViewList", "My"))
        .Mode(LoadMode.Script)
        .Params(new { listId = Model.ListId })))
```

The view looks like this:

```
@model ItemViewModel
@{
    var x = Html.X();
}

@(x.Panel()
   .LayoutConfig(new HBoxLayoutConfig {Align = HBoxAlign.StretchMax})
    .Flex(1)
    .Items(
        x.Button().Text("Temp").Flex(1)))
```

My issue is that I cannot seem to get the partial view to render. It comes back as either a white box if I set `WrapByScriptTag` to true - in which case I get an error stating "Uncaught ReferenceError: Ext is not defined") or I get the component's JavaScript as text if I set `WrapByScriptTag` to false. I know I'm missing a setting somewhere but I'm not sure what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to change my controller to use `RenderMode.Config` and to change the `renderer` option on the loader from `"frame"` to `"component"`. The difference, as I understand it, is that the frame option tells Ext.JS to expect an IFrame (i.e. fully-formed HTML) whereas the component option is used to described Ext components. That was half the problem. The other half was that I was trying to render the component so it would be added into another container's `Items` field but the request originated from a call to `add` so this was unnecessary. Rather, rendering the component as a config made more sense because it was a partial view.

Note that this works in Ext.NET 4.2.0 but not Ext.NET 4.1.0. In that case choosing `renderer: "script"` fixed the problem.